# Sharing location using asmack

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, smack

I am working on a chat Application on android platform. I want to share my current location through PubSub in xmpp library. Can anyone give me code that how use pubsub API's.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Smack documentation](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html) on this API should suffice.

The [testcases for pubsub](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/test/org/jivesoftware/smackx/pubsub) in Smack would be another source of code examples.

Answer (score 0):

[pubsub-android](https://github.com/pubsubio/pubsub-android) is a library with some examples. See the examples included with the library.